# Create a tree view in c# on SharePoint Online Document Library Basis with CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I want to create a Treeview in C#. My basic data is stored in a SharePoint Online DocumentLibrary. I authenticate with a user and I want to show the folders and files as a tree view in Azure function where the user has the permissions to. On that bases the user should see the following tree.

The view should be like that:

```
 Folder1
      Folder11
         Document.docx
         Document.pdf
      Folder12
         Document.xslx
   Folder2
      Folder21
      Folder22
        Folder221
            Document.json
        Folder222
```

etc.

Maybe you can help me with this approach.

Thanks

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to following code to enable tree view

```
clientContext.Web.TreeViewEnabled = true;
clientContext.Web.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: that's not I was looking for. I meant programmatically. I have a rootfolder of a document library and then I get recusively all the folder and file like in the example. thanks